# Touch area doesnt move after translate animation

Tags: android, android-layout

I m sliding down the Layout (which has different ImageView), from top to bottom using **TranslateAnimation**, but when it get slide, its Touchable area still stick to previous position, it doesnt move downwards along with ImageView, it is showing visually that its Y axis get moved from some value, but its touchable area still at original place.

Please help me in solving this problem.

I have used this for sliding animation :

```
TranslateAnimation t =new TranslateAnimation(0, 0,0,35);
t.setDuration(200);
t.setFillAfter(true);   
t.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
menuSlideBgId.startAnimation(t);
inFram.startAnimation(t);
```

---

This is my lyaout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:gravity="left|right"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/bg_android"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/thinknsay" />

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rLay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


      <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/menuSlideBg"
              android:layout_width="339dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="452dp"
              android:layout_height="35dp"
              android:src="@drawable/menu_slide3" />      

          <RelativeLayout
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/slideNavLayout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="550dp" >

              <ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/bubbleMenu"
                  android:layout_width="28dp"
                  android:layout_height="28dp"
                  android:layout_gravity="left"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
                  android:layout_marginTop="455dp"
                  android:src="@drawable/buble_icon" />

              <ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/shareMenuId"
                  android:layout_width="28dp"
                  android:layout_height="28dp"
                  android:layout_gravity="left"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="225dp"
                  android:layout_marginTop="455dp"
                  android:onClick="shareMenu"
                  android:src="@drawable/share_icon" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TranslateAnimation` just re-draws the view at different positions over time, it doesn't really moves the `View`. You need to change its layout position also, [`ObjectAnimator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) can be used to change `View` properties.

Comment: and how about the FrameAnimation, i have set of Images that i can move with creating XML in res->anim and writing <item android:drawable="@drawable/flip1" android:duration="25" /> but problem is same, the touchable area still at same place, how can i achieve FrameAnimation with moved touchable area?